# JavaScript: find pop-up window by URL and close it

Tags: javascript, dom

I have several pop-up windows opened.

I need to find the one that has specific URL and close it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you show some code? How did you open them?

Comment: I did not open these windows myself. I'm using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM which takes care of opening the new pop-up windows. I can execute JavaScript from some windows, but not that particular one.

Comment: I doubt there is a builtin mechanism for that, so you'll have to resort to keeping all popups in an associative array with the URL as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have references to them (i.e. you have kept the return value from `open`) and the URLs are on the same domain as your page (you cannot sniff anything about the content of a window on a different domain for security reasons) then you can iterate over those return values (this is easiest if you keep them in an array) and test `retVal.location` to see if it matches the value you are looking for.

Update with respect to a comment on the question that was added while I wrote the above:

There is no way to ask the browser what other windows are open, even if they were opened by the same page so you would have to modify the CRM you are using.